# Flink: handling deletion of records filtered out in a temporary view

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a Flink application that reads from a couple Kafka sources using the `debezium-json` format and generates a materialized view by joining + filtering + aggregating them. I'm using the Table API w/ SQL so the sources are defined as so:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 user_id INT,
 is_deleted BOOLEAN
) WITH (
 'connector' = 'kafka',
 'topic' = 'cdc.users',
 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '<brokers>'
 'properties.group.id' = '1',
 'format' = 'debezium-json',
 'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset'
)
```

**Kafka Source 1:** `users`

| user_id | is_deleted |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | false |
| 2 | false |

**Kafka Source 2:** `purchases`

| user_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | flink_for_dummies |
| 1 | intro_to_table_api |
| 2 | flink_for_dummies |

The materialized view is generated using the query below and output to a Elasticsearch sink.

```
SELECT 
 user_id,
 COUNT(product_id) as purchases_count
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN purchases p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE is_deleted = FALSE
```

**Materialized View**

| user_id | purchases_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

I'm also converting the temporary view table to a DataStream before outputting it to the sink.

```
Table table = tableEnv.sqlQuery("<materialized_view_query>");
DataStream<Row> ds = tableEnv.toChangelogStream(table)....
```

This works as expected expect until I start deleting users. For example -- if I set `user 2` to have `is_deleted=true`, I'd expecting to see a row with the `DELETE` row-kind for `user 2` emitted in the temporary view but instead I see no update at all. I suspect this is either a misunderstanding on my part with how Dynamic Tables / changelog streams work or I've setup the Table -> DataStream conversion incorrectly.

I did try logging the output of the sources / view. For the Kafka sources I see `INSERT_BEFORE` and `INSERT_AFTER` events as expected. For the temporary however, I only ever see `INSERT` row records when the user is not deleted and no records at all when they are deleted.

Is this expected or is there a way to have the view generate delete events for records that are now filtered out?

Comment: Have you configured your TableEnvironment in streaming mode? https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/api/java/

Answer (score 1):

I attempted this again and was able to get it to work as expected. The only changes I made were to use `ChangelogMode.upsert()` and ensure primary keys were set.

```
tableEnv.toChangelogStream(
      table,
      Schema.newBuilder().primaryKey("user_id").build(),
      ChangelogMode.upsert())
```

```
tableEnv.fromChangelogStream(
      datastream,
      Schema.newBuilder().primaryKey("user_id").build(),
      ChangelogMode.upsert())
```

Comment: This is still not work in my case.